VScode dev container is taking very long time to download deps and build. How can I backup and reuse it locally?
Currently I am waiting for torch download (pip) for 30 minutes already. My internet is fine, just some things are slow to download. To avoid this in the future, can I take my local dev image, back it up and reuse it later on? With all the dependencies included.
OS Linux Fedora 41 if that matters
